# ViewPager

Tags: android-viewpager, android

Доброго времени суток.
У меня приложение ориентировано на api 11 и выше, наверное дико туплю но не могу найти ViewPager  для старших версий, без support library

Comment: этот компонент на сколько я знаю только и есть в support v4

Comment: А что конкретно Вы хотите сделать с использованием ViewPager?

Comment: навигацию между фрагментам

Comment: тогда вам сюда

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Comment: в том то и дело, что FragmentPagerAdapter работает с Fragment из support, и на вход ему нужен не android.app.FragmentManager а android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager и соответственно нужно использовать android.support.v4.app.Fragment и вызывать это все из под FragmentActivity

Comment: посмотрите вот этот ответ на стеке

http://stackoverflow.com/a/15414598/1233682

Comment: А в чем загвоздка то? Почему Вы не хотите использовать android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: по мне так лучше использовать фраменты из саппорта, потому что  саппорт хотя бы обновляется иногда, в отличие от фрагментов в ОС.

Answer (score 1):

Я воспользовался для решения данной проблемы советы выше - добавил библиотеку android.support.v13 и использовал ViewPager из нее, так как она способна, в отличии от v4 использовать (например для метода getItem) android.app.Fragment, а не android.support.app.v4.Fragment